# Is there a way to disable resonably close version matching with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

npm has the ability to match non-exact versions of direct and transitive dependencies.

https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html

As an example if you depend on a module/library that is v1.2.3 and you declare this dependency in package.json as

```
"foo": "~1.2.3"
```

with the `~` character you may actually resolve any version of `foo` prior to `1.3.0` including any versions marked as `-beta`.

Is there a way to disable this loose/fuzzy matching so that dependency resolution is more consistent?

As an example, if the above dependency was in place, then the version resolved would always be 1.2.3.

Most importantly, this would also need to hold true for transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [npm shrinkwrap](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html) is what you are looking for. Once you have a set of installed dependencies you want to freeze for deployment, run `npm shrinkwrap` and the entire dependency tree with all versions will be locked into place.

This is a somewhat new feature (Feb 2012, ok not that new) and I haven't seen that much adoption yet, but officially this is the solution to your concerns. Another approach folks take is just never use any wildcards in their dependency versions: "1.2.3", which is mostly sufficient for applications but is frowned upon for reusable modules.

More details about the reasoning behind npm shrinkwrap are in [the blog post from when it was announced](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/).

Comment: Although I haven't got it working yet, based on the documentation this looks like a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default npm installs packages using ^ which means any version in the same major range, you can switch this behaviour by using --save-exact.

This only works for the parent dependencies, for child dependencies you would need to use npm shrinkwrap or yarn lock files.

```
// npm
npm install --save --save-exact react

// yarn
yarn add --exact react
```

I created a blog post about saving exact if anyone is looking for this in the future.

https://www.dalejefferson.com/blog/how-to-save-exact-npm-package-versions/